# restriction on java api to be called a fix number of time in a day

Tags: java, url, restriction

I want to restrict user to call my api for a limited number of time in. My api is java controller url.
Can any one suggest how i can do this with out using db.

Comment: You'll need some sort of data storage either way. You can put in an XML file or a normal textfile but in the end a database will be a lot easier to maintain and work with.

Comment: Hi I can do that by using any cache mechanism or Db but it will always create one extra look up so i wanted to know that is there any URL parameter which can handle this or we can do it using web.xml